# GLSL pre 3.30 attribute allocation

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm writing code for a computer I currently do not have access to so testing on a more modern laptop.

To pass vertex and colour info (that are in a interleaved array) to the GPU I'm using

```
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexVBoid);
glVertexAttribPointer (0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(c_vertex), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
glVertexAttribPointer (1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(c_vertex),       BUFFER_OFFSET(3*sizeof(vertex_store[0][0].x)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray (0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray (1);
```

vertex shader is

```
void main()
{
gl_Position = ftransform();
gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
}
```

fragment shader is

```
void main(){
gl_FragColor=gl_Color;
}
```

plots the correct shape but with no colour - trying to use as "old" a version of GLSL as possible to ensure backward compatibility.

So how do I pick up the colour information in the shader (and I'm also passing normal info too)

Comment: You need to read about `attribute variables`. And another thing: on old OpenGL you should use `glGetAttribLocation()` to get attribute locations instead of using these `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing fixed function vertex attributes with generic vertex attributes.

The `gl_Position` and `gl_Color` attributes in your vertex shader correspond to fixed function attributes. On the other hand, the `glVertexAttribPointer()` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` calls are for generic vertex attributes. Mixing the two works on some platforms, but it is not a safe and robust thing to do.

You need to change one or the other:

- Use generic attributes in the vertex shader. You do that by declaring your own variables, instead of using `gl_Position` and `gl_Color`. The variables you declare have the `attribute` qualifier in older GL versions, or the `in` qualifier for the current core profile. You also need to associate these variables with an attribute location, either using a `layout(location = ..)` qualifier in the shader code if you're ok with using at least GL 3.3, or by calling `glBindAttribLocation()` before linking the shader.
- Use the calls to set up the fixed function vertex attributes instead of `glVertexAttribPointer()` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray()`: `glVertexPointer()`, `glColorPointer()` and `glEnableClientState()`.

Comment: As a side note, one could mention that attribute index 0 is actually guaranteed to alias the `gl_Vertex` attribute. But it is probably still better to avoid such things.

Comment: @derhass: I don't think that works with all drivers/platforms. It could probably be argued that those drivers are broken, but since it's unlikely to get fixed, it's much safer to not rely on it.

Comment: The language that guarantees that behavior is a little vague. What is for certain guaranteed is that specifying generic vertex attribute **0** in immediate mode is equivalent to `glVertex{1|2|3|4} (...)` in that it denotes the end of a vertex. Whether that means that generic vertex attribute **0** has to alias to `gl_Vertex` is not clear, but every GL implementation I have worked on seems to interpret it that way. Historically, generic attribute **0** aliased to `POSITION` in the ARB Vertex Program assembly language; NV honors the full set of ARBVP1 aliases even in GLSL, other vendors do not.